# Dropdown - Default selection

Tags: javascript, laravel, dropdown

First I want to say Hi to everyone!

OK, my problem is quite simple. I want to show the first Category and his first Sub-Category. It's **Laravel**. I want to remove the "Select a category" and "Select a sub-category" and for default I want the first string from the list.

Thank you!

**Category:**

```
<select name="parent" id="parent" class="form-control selecter">                                                
    <option value="0" data-type=""
            @if(old('parent')=='' or old('parent')==0)selected="selected"@endif> {{ t('Select a category') }} </option>
    @foreach ($categories as $cat)                                                  
        <option value="{{ $cat->tid }}" data-type="{{ $cat->type }}"                                                        
                @if(old('parent')==$cat->tid)selected="selected"@endif> {{ $cat->name }} </option>                                                              
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**Sub-Category:**

```
<select name="category" id="category" class="form-control selecter">
    <option value="0"
            @if(old('category')=='' or old('category')==0)selected="selected"@endif> {{ t('Select a sub-category') }} </option>
</select>
```

**And the script:**

```
<script>
    /* Categories */
    var category = {{ old('parent', 0) }};
    var categoryType = '{{ old('parent_type') }}';
    if (categoryType=='') {
        var selectedCat = $('select[name=parent]').find('option:selected');
        categoryType = selectedCat.data('type');
    }
    var subCategory = {{ old('category', 0) }};
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, what is the problem?

Comment: I need to see the first category name from the list not the "Select a category". The same with the Sub-Category.